# Uploading to Google Merchant Centre

Tags: feed, google-shopping-api

I am having difficulty in uploading my feed to Google Shopping. **How can I upload my product feed to "Google Shopping"?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,uploading to google is very easy. There are just certain steps you have to fulfill in order to upload your feed to google merchant. You can see it here:[Uploading product feed to google merchant center](http://www.exportfeed.com/documentation/upload-data-feeds-via-automatic-upload-to-google-merchant-center/). 
Still having difficulty you contact us from here :[ExportFeed.com](http://www.exportfeed.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can see code sample for different programing languages here

[Content API Code Samples From Google](https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/v2/libraries)